# can't write to file first time

Tags: javascript, file

There is a code where I check for the existence of a file. And if the file does not exist, then I create it. And then I write to this file.
The problem is that I get an error when I try to write to a file. And when I run the code again everything works fine because the file already exists.

I think that this error occurs because I create a file in error handling. And after create file I immediately start writing in it

My error

```
> node .\app.js
file not exist: ./config/config.json
```

My code

```
exports.postMySQLconfigSave = function(request, response){
    let jsonFile;
    let jsonFile2;
    let configData;    

   fs.access(PathConfigFile, function(error){
    if (error){
        console.log("file not exist: " + PathConfigFile);    
        jsonFile =JSON.stringify({});   //create JSON
        fs.writeFileSync(PathConfigFile, jsonFile);
        };
    });

    jsonFile = fs.readFileSync(PathConfigFile, "utf8"); //read all files with config by JSON
    configData = JSON.parse(jsonFile);                  //conver to JS format

    if (configData.MySQL == undefined) {    //check exist key MySQL in file if not exist then create new key
        configData.MySQL={};
        console.log("not MySQL config");
    };
    if (configData.MySQL.IpAddress == undefined) {    //check exist key IpAddress in file if not exist then create new key
        configData.MySQL.IpAddress="";
        console.log("not IpAddress MySQL");
    };
    if (configData.MySQL.Login == undefined) {    //check exist key Login in file if not exist then create new key
        configData.MySQL.Login="";
        console.log("not Login MySQL");
    };
    if (configData.MySQL.Password == undefined) {    //check exist key Password in file if not exist then create new key
        configData.MySQL.Password="";
        console.log("not Password MySQL");
    };
    
    
    configData.MySQL.IpAddress = request.body.IPaddressMySQL;
    configData.MySQL.Login = request.body.LoginMySQL;
    configData.MySQL.Password = request.body.PasswordMySQL;    

    jsonFile =JSON.stringify(configData);

    fs.writeFileSync(PathConfigFile, jsonFile);
    console.log("Here was the code");
    response.send("About the site");
};
```

Comment: You're not handling the error right. Try to `console.log(error);` so you can see the real error

Answer (score 0):

```
export function access(path: PathLike, callback: NoParamCallback): void;
    export namespace access {
        /**
         * Asynchronously tests a user's permissions for the file specified by path.
         * @param path A path to a file or directory. If a URL is provided, it must use the `file:` protocol.
         * URL support is _experimental_.
         */
```

Comment: This answer feels incomplete. If you were trying to add to your question, you can go back and edit the question. If you feel this code fragment can adequately answer the question, then please elaborate